# Bootstrap navbar using angular routes glitches to left side on specific active tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, bootstrap-4

Sorry if it is a dumb question, I am a beginner to web design and couldn't find an answer, even after a lot of googling / searching on here.

So as you can read in the title, my issue is, that upon clicking on "EX5" or "EX6" in my navbar, it glitches to the left side of the screen, instead of staying at the top.

Below is my code, since EX5 and EX6 are basically the same thing, I'll post the shorter one in here:

Navbar:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app='sampleApp'>
    
    <head>
        <link data-require="bootstrap-css" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
        <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular-route.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
        <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/headerController.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
      <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" ng-controller="HeaderController">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">JS</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/')}"><a href="#/ex1">EX1</a></li>
              <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/ex2')}"><a href="#/ex2">EX2</a></li>
              <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/ex3')}"><a href="#/ex3">EX3</a></li>
              <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/ex4')}"><a href="#/ex4">EX4</a></li>
              <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/ex5')}"><a href="#/ex5">EX5</a></li>
              <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/ex6')}"><a href="#/ex6">EX6</a></li>
              <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/ex7')}"><a href="#/ex7">EX7</a></li>
              <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/ex8')}"><a href="#/ex8">EX8</a></li>
              <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/ex9')}"><a href="#/ex9">EX9</a></li>
              <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/ex10')}"><a href="#/ex10">EX10</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <ng-view></ng-view>
    </body>
    </html>
```

EX6:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/stylesheet.css"> 
        <title>Exercise 6</title>
        <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h2>Add an image, upon clicking, change the image</h2>
            <hr>
            <img onclick="changeImg()" id="sourceImg" src="../styles/images/diluc.jpg" alt="diluc">
        </div>
        
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

script:

```
//change img
var currentImage = "../styles/images/diluc.jpg"

function changeImg(){
  if(currentImage == "../styles/images/diluc.jpg"){
  document.getElementById("sourceImg").src="../styles/images/venti.jpg";
  currentImage = "../styles/images/venti.jpg"
}else{
  document.getElementById("sourceImg").src = "../styles/images/diluc.jpg"
  currentImage = "../styles/images/diluc.jpg"
}
}

/////Nav
(function () {

  var app = angular.module('sampleApp',['ngRoute']);
  
  app.config(function ($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider
          .when('/',{
              templateUrl:'../exercises/ex1.html'
          })
          .when('/ex2',{
              templateUrl:'../exercises/ex2.html'
          })
          .when('/ex3',{
              templateUrl:'../exercises/ex3.html'
          })
          .when('/ex4',{
            templateUrl:'../exercises/ex4.html'
          })  
          .when('/ex5',{
            templateUrl:'../exercises/ex5.html'
          })  
          .when('/ex6',{
            templateUrl:'../exercises/ex6.html'
          })  
          .when('/ex7',{
            templateUrl:'../exercises/ex7.html'
          })  
          .when('/ex8',{
            templateUrl:'../exercises/ex8.html'
          })  
          .when('/ex9',{
            templateUrl:'../exercises/ex9.html'
          })  
          .when('/ex10',{
            templateUrl:'../exercises/ex10.html'
          })  
          .otherwise({ redirectTo:'/'});
  });
})();
```

My header controller:

```
(function () { 
 
    var headerController = function ($scope, $location) 
      { 
          $scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) { 
              return viewLocation === $location.path();
          };
      };
      
      angular.module('sampleApp').controller('HeaderController',headerController);
  }());
```

And lastly my 3 lines of css:

```
#sourceImg{
    width: 500px;
}
```

I would greatly appreciate your help, as I am unable to solve this myself. Thank you

Comment: Okay, I found the issue: My own stylesheet clashes with bootstrap. Trying to resolve rn

Answer (score 0):

Solved, issue was with my css file, there was some gibberish in there oof